# expo notifiee FCM notification app not opening

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using notifiee FCM legacy in my expo app. When user Send message, I get notification but when I tap, app is not opening. But when user sends more than 4 messages, then it groups the messages in single notification and when I tap on them the app is opening. But why it doesn't open when there is single message as default behavior is to open the app on click.
I am using expo 49, notifee 7.8, react-native-firebase/app 18.7.3

**Index.js**

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig).then(() => {
        notifee.onBackgroundEvent(async ({ type, detail }) => {
            const { notification, pressAction } = detail;

            if (EventType.ACTION_PRESS){
                const toUser = {_id:notification.id, displayName:notification.title, }
                console.log('pressed notification')
                // nav.navigate(notification.data.screen, notification.data.params)
            }
        });
        messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(message => {
            const {notification} = message
            console.log(notification)
        })
        messaging().getInitialNotification(async remoteMessage => {
            console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
        });
    })
```

I want to also navigate to other screen on tap. But I cannot use dispatch, useNavigation or any hook in index.js file. So how to solve this problem ?